How to compare date through rule with jsonLogic.Net
I am using jsonLogic net to validate input data. Want to compare the input date with the date defined in Rule. But Not able to find date operator. Is there any way to compare the dates without parsing the input data?
I can parse the date or current date using place holders defined in rule. But how to compare it with the date provided in input data?

Hi im not too familiar with the library, but i threw together a quick unit test based off the sample from the github library. As dates in json are just strings, if you have control of the format, i think the standard less than / greater than operators should still work, provided that the times are standardized in UTC and in 24 hour format.
using FluentAssertions;
using JsonLogic.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace FunctionTesting.Json.JsonLogic;

public class JsonLogicTests
{
    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(SampleTests))]
    public void JsonLogic_TestDateEvaluator(string op, DateTime sampleDate, DateTime ruleDate, bool expectedResult)
    {
        //arrange
        // The data that the rule will run against.
        var format = "yyyyMMddTHH:mm:ss";
        object data = new {MyDate = sampleDate.ToString(format)};

        // Rule definition retrieved as JSON text
        string jsonText=$"{{\"{op}\": [{{\"var\": \"MyDate\"}}, \"{ruleDate.ToString(format)}\"]}}";
        var rule = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
        var operators = EvaluateOperators.Default;
        
        var evaluator = new JsonLogicEvaluator(operators);
        
        // act
        object result = evaluator.Apply(rule, data);
        
        // assert
        result.Should().BeOfType<bool>().And.Be(expectedResult);

    }

    public static IEnumerable<object[]> SampleTests()
    {
        var sampleDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        yield return new object[] { ">", sampleDate, sampleDate.AddDays(-1), true };
        yield return new object[] { "<", sampleDate, sampleDate.AddDays(-1), false };
        yield return new object[] { "<", sampleDate, sampleDate.AddDays(1), true };
        yield return new object[] { ">", sampleDate, sampleDate.AddDays(1), false };
        yield return new object[] { "==", sampleDate, sampleDate, true };
    }
}

You should be able to add test cases for this for your use case, but if there are restrictions, you might have to add custom operators that would then end out parsing the dates.

Thank you @pedrosbanioles.
Actually problem is that I have input data as a whole object and some properties are of dateTime type(not in UTC format) and I don't want to parse whole object to update the dates format only.
I was wondering if there is some existing date operator in jsonLogic package and I can achieve the comparison by only adding the rules. Otherwise, I have to write the custom operators.

Unfortunately the last commit on the repo was back in 2021 and looking at the source for the operators there isnt much support for date times.  This issue was the closest that came to a discussion about dates.
The author is also looking for another maintainer, so I would suspect the custom operators would be the way to go unfortunately.

Got it.
Will write custom operators.
Thank you
